# versioning stored procedures/PLSQL?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, versioning

Is there an efficient way to version store procedures written in PL/SQL? (I only mention PL/SQL because there may exist a particular tool, any answer directed to versioning of stored procedures is ideal).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, nor packages.

Comment: Can you define this more carefully?  I think of versioning of an artifact as having one or more variants derived from a base.  From that perspective, "versioned PL/SQL" means "slightly different PL/SQL scripts".  What's hard about this?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: getting others to do it.

Comment: Accuse me being humorless.  But I don't understand the problem.  Others here seem to have interpreted the question as "use a version control system" (and if that's the problem, there's nothing hard about it; in fact you don't you'll soon find out the consequences of not doing it).  But I'm assuming that isn't the question, because you didn't state it that way, and the answer is so well known I don't know why you would ask.   Can you please clarify, by giving an example and a response longer than 5 short words?

Comment: Where I work, non of the PL/SQL is versioned. It has been like this for awhile. It wouldn't be possible to tell the developers to start using version control for PL/SQL, and then actually assume (with any confidence) that *all* stored procedures are checked in. It is likely that someone will forget to check in, and you end up with a situation of "who has the prior to the latest version"/rollback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my current job , the team is now using the following method to version control the PL/SQL .When compiling the PL/SQL ,  no matter compile successfully or not  , a record will be inserted into the log table . Besides in the mid-night , there is an JAVA agent to be scheduled to run automatically check if the PL/SQL source needed to check into the CVS.

### Update

Link to blog now is [AMIS TECHNOLOGY BLOG](https://technology.amis.nl/2005/10/12/plsql-source-code-control-inside-the-database-after-compile-trigger-for-automatic-archiving/)

---

The following link no longer works

http://technology.amis.nl/blog/846/plsql-source-code-control-inside-the-database-after-compile-trigger-for-automatic-archiving

Comment: We employ a similar system to this at my job as well. My main issue with it is that there's not much info to go with the check-in. We can't tell what code changes relate to which issue in our bug-tracking system. There's no "why" when we look at the history, just users and dates. Also, there's a lot of noise, as the incomplete work gets a check-in as well. We haven't found a good way to deal with these things.

Comment: Hi @AdamHawkes. Full disclousre, I am the founder of Gitora, the product I am referring to. But solutions for this problem are rare so I think it is worth mentioning. We do a lot of database development with PL/SQL and have been suffering from the same issues. We built a solution for PL/SQL which addresses exactly the issues mentioned in this answer. We built a product that bridges Git with the Oracle Database so that PL/SQL developers can manage their code base in Git like, say, Java developers. Hope it helps.

Comment: Downvoted as link no longer works... and that's exactly why the answer should not be just a link but an actual explanation

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a 'regular' version control system?  All of our deployed/deployable stored procs are controlled just like application code.

It's been a while since I've dealt with PL/SQL, so I don't have anything to offer on the package definitions.

Granted, this isn't *in* the database, but...

Answer (score 3):

We built a tool so that we can manage our PL/SQL code in the Oracle Database. It hooks Git to the Oracle database and helps you manage your PL/SQL code base easily. You can do basic Git tasks such as commiting, resetting, branching, cloning, merging, pulling etc... and Gitora automatically updates the PL/SQL code in the database.

You can download it at [www.gitora.com](http://www.gitora.com/).

Comment: I like the solution (your product), but your answer isn't valid anymore as your solution isn't free anymore. So now you're answer could be seen as spam now

Comment: I totally forgot about this answer I gave. :-). I updated my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's free [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) tool has integration with CVS and Subversion for version control of PL/SQL code.

Comment: could you elaborate on the use of it? And the link is not valid anymore

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the link. I'm afraid I can't elaborate on version control within SQL Developer though as I don't actually use it!