# Oracle database, large plsql code managment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on project, where business logic is implemented in oracle database, using plsql. Code base is becoming big and it's management is becoming nightmare.

For example when code base is in Java, C#, ... you have version control system for project, where history is stored, and you are managing project with branches, tags etc. I do not understand how this can be done with pl/sql code which is stored directly in database server.

I want to know for situations like this, what are best practice of managing plsql codebase ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [versioning stored procedures/PLSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390029/versioning-stored-procedures-plsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working with Oracle for something like 20 years, and never seen a satisfactory code management system in use.

However, in the past year I've been working on Ruby on Rails apps, with the distributed version control system "git" augmented by gitflow to help formalise the code branches (master, develop, feature, hotfix etc) and deployment of database (PostgreSQL) migrations using rake. I really wish I'd had the opportunity to use them with Oracle code because it really ticks every box I needed.

Comment: For the Oracle and HTML/Javascript apps we're building with very small teams we're using Subversion and some home-rolled build and deployment scripts. I want to redo the build/deployment scripts using make. Subversion is very bad at branching and merging so we don't use it instead rapidly deploying new versions.

Comment: That was my (limited) experience with Subversion also. The branching ought to be easy of course, and the trick in merging really ought to just come down to dealing with individual files diffs, which is more a matter I think of what tool you prefer for that. You might like to look at git and gitflow if you need something stronger for branch management. I know that Corporate types would revolt against it, but github.com is a very handy repository service too.

Answer (score 10):

There's no reason to only store PL/SQL in the database just because some client tools default to working that way.

I strongly recommend you choose your favourite source control system and store PL/SQL sources in it. Use an all.sql to create all PL/SQL packages and other create-or-replace objects.

See [versioning stored procedures/PLSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390029/versioning-stored-procedures-plsql) for an alternative approach but this requires a bit more effort to setup.

Comment: What tools can be used to develop plsql offline, without database connection ?

Comment: Notepad? vi? Any text editor will do, but there are some with syntax highlighting such as vim and UltraEdit.

Comment: There's no reason not to have multiple databases for development -- each developer can have their own. Check with your oracle sales rep but the license generally allows that.

Comment: A very good point; another approach is to have one database per "role". We try to have one database which is stable for the front-end developers to develop against, while the back-end developers have a database with a stable front-end.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure all of your PL/SQL is scripted externally before it is applied to the database, and put those files under source control. My tool of choice is TortiseHG.

I would be very unhappy if the only place my stored proc definitions, etc, existed was on the database, partially for the same reason you are bringing this up.

Comment: agree. there is no difference between c#/Java and PL/Sql. use external source control. i use svn.

Answer (score 2):

We built a tool so that we can manage our PL/SQL code in the Oracle Database. It hooks Git to the Oracle database and helps you manage your PL/SQL code base easily. You can do basic Git tasks such as commiting, resetting, branching, cloning, merging, pulling etc... and Gitora automatically updates the PL/SQL code in the database.

You can download it at [www.gitora.com](http://www.gitora.com/)

Comment: We recently released a new version which enables developers move (pull in Git jargon) code between two databases.